# How to export PDF from Google Docs without over-compressing graphics in header

Tags: pdf, graphics, google-docs, image-compression

For setting up a letterhead style layout in Google Docs, we find it handy to put a logo in the header section. However, when the Google Doc is downloaded as a PDF, the image is over-compressed, making it very lossy and unprofessional.

This is a 100px square logo graphic that looks crisp when viewed in Finder, any graphics application, and from within Google Docs. I have tried different formats (PNG at 5KB, JPG 100 at 16KB) to see if this would change the compression algorithm, but it looks rubbish either way. It doesn't matter if I choose File > Download as PDF or Print > Save within Google Docs.

The one workaround so far seems to be using a large logo graphic PNG, which seems rather counterintuitive but it comes out looking fine. Of course the PDF file size is then substantially larger.

Does anyone know what's up with the Google Doc compression for graphics in PDFs? Is this only an issue for graphics in the header/footer? Anything else I should try other than jumbo files? Thank you!

Comment: Hello — I found a workaround for my issue by using a PNG with alpha channel, looks like Google Docs treats these differently and doesn't want to compress them.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer so other people may benefit from it.

Answer (score 7):

Use the "Print" button, this will open the browsers print dialog. There you can choose "Microsoft to PDF" (if you are using windows) or any other "To PDF" option.
This will preserve PNGs.
[image]